# Which is the correct XOR Gate Symbol

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm confused between 2 XOR gate symbols, they have a minor difference but I'd still like to know if they truly are identical.

One looks like - [image: this]

The other, like [image: this]

Notice, how for one of them the input lines are connected all the way and for the other, it's not. Are they both identical, as I suspect or is there something I'm not aware about?

Comment: I cannot see your images.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Really? They should work fine, might be an issue on your side.

Comment: They work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a standard for this, ANSI/IEEE Std 91a-1991. The second version is what that standard gives for the "distinctive shape symbol" (5.1-11). So if you want to know what one is "correct", it's arguably that.

[image: ANSI/IEE Std 91a-1991 EOR symbol]

The other version is not the standard, but it's extremely common and everyone knows what you mean by it. But it's not distinct.

Answer (score 0):

This is akin to asking if $B$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are really the same letter and, if not, which is correct. It makes no difference.